# How to let my mask do not overflow the panel?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to put my loading mask on the panel form.
The example below doesn't work as expected, the mask is overflowing the panel body. How do I make the mask width 100% of the panel body.

```css
.mask {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.5);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 150px;
  z-index: 9999;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.mask .loading {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  background-color: #666666;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 22px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
    <h2>Panel Mask</h2>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
    <div class="panel panel-default" style="box-sizing: border-box;">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="mask">
          <span class="loading">
            <i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i><span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>Loading...
          </span>
        </div>
        <form class="form-horizontal">
          <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="username">名稱</label>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <input name="username" id="username" class="form-control input-md">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="description">備註</label>
              <div class="col-md-8">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="description" name="description"></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
              <div class="col-md-8">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="save()">Update</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the top and left property to your mask.

Then, remove the width property, and add a 15px margin from the right (`right: 15px`), because the gutter of bootstrap containers is 15px.

And here you go.

```css
.mask {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(102,102,102,0.5);
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 150px;
  z-index: 9999;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 15px;
}
.mask .loading {
  margin: 0 auto;
 display: block;
 background-color: #666666;
 color: #ffffff;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 22px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1"><h2>Panel Mask</h2></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
    <div class="panel panel-default" style="box-sizing: border-box;">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="mask">
          <span class="loading">
            <i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i><span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>Loading...
          </span>
        </div>
        <form class="form-horizontal">
          <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="username">名稱</label>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <input name="username" id="username" class="form-control input-md">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="description">備註</label>
              <div class="col-md-8">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="description" name="description"></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-3 control-label" ></label>
              <div class="col-md-8">
                <button type="button"  class="btn btn-default" (click)="save()" >Update</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Still the mask leaves the panel border on the left. Perhaps adding `overflow:hidden` on the `.panel-default` might fix this.

Comment: No it doesn't ? It's not "leaving the panel" on the left, it's covering the border too.

Comment: Apologies if my comment isn't clear. See in this image what I mean https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDjnq.png.

Comment: Thank so much!! I forget bootstrap column has gutters! I add `padding-right: 0; padding-left: 0;` to my column div and add `margin: top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;` to `.panel-default`. it's better than original.

Comment: Now mask is still not on correct postion, I think because of `.panel-body` `padding: 15px;`.

Comment: So I follow your advice adding `top: 0; left: 0; right: 15px;` to my mask, it's do well now!!! Thanks!!

Comment: Well no problem ! Remember to mark your question as resolved :)